# Code compiles on AIX 5.3 but not AIX 7.1 something to do with struct shl_descriptor where is this defined?

Tags: c, unix, aix

I have some code that looks similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/ldr.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   int                      liRC = 0;
   struct shl_descriptor    *lstModDesc;
   int                      liEach;
   char                     lsBaseName[513];
   char                     *lsTheName;

   for( liEach = 0; liRC == 0; liEach++ )
   {
      liRC = shl_get( liEach, &lstModDesc );
      if( liRC == 0 )
      {
         strcpy( lsBaseName, lstModDesc->filename );
         lsTheName = (char *)basename( lsBaseName );
         /* do more stuff */
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

What it is doing is enumerating all the shared libraries attached to the binary.  This compiles fine on AIX 5.3 but on AIX 7.1 I am getting the following concerning lstModDesc:

> "modulename.c", line 2553.30: 1506-285
>   (S) The indirection operator cannot be
>   a pplied to a pointer to an incomplete
>   struct or union.

I cannot find where shl_get is defined on my aix 5.3 box nor can I find where struct shl_descriptor is defined either.  I am stumped.  I even tried outputing the preprocessed output with the -E flag to the compiler with no luck.  I did a recursive grep in /usr/include.  Is there somewhere else I should be searching?  Where are those definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that bit of the code was included in the compilation on AIX 5.3?  I just went Google-whacking with 'site:ibm.com shl_descriptor' and there is precisely one item found:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21212239

It is pointing to a problem on HP-UX with WAS (WebSphere Application Server).  There is sample code which uses `<dl.h>` (dynamic loader), and shows `shl_descriptor` and `shl_gethandle()` and `shl_load()`.

Given the complete absence of hits for anything in AIX and the presence of the HP-UX platform, then you have a slightly different problem to resolve.  The question is:

- Why is the conditional compilation on AIX 5.3 excluding the section that uses `shl_descriptor` and not excluding it on AIX 7.1.  You should look at the conditions wrapped around that code in the `#ifdef` line, and see what is used to trigger the HP-only compilation on AIX 5.3.

Comment: Good call the whole function was excluded by defines for AIX4.3 AIX5.2 and AIX5.1 way above it so it got hidden away.  Took a while but you were right in the end.